# How do I remove a view from a super view without unloading the superview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to something like `[view removeFromSuperview]` however when I do it appears from what I've seen and what I've read in the apple documentation that the normal behaviour is to remove the superview from view as well (unless I have misread).

I'm wondering how to simply remove a view from the superview, i.e. in the case of creating a modal window, then releasing it, and redrawing again later

Answer (score 6):

You are mistaken. Just call:

```
[subview removeFromSuperview];
```

Why don't you just try this out? Takes 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling `removeFromSuperview` on the wrong view. It should be called on the view you want to remove, *not* its superview.

The `removeFromSuperview` method removes the receiving view from its superview. It does not also remove the receiving view's superview from *its* superview as you suggest.